# Why does this gorilla session code not work?

Tags: session, go, gorilla

I'm a golang noob, so I'm making my first toy app by setting up a seed project for a gorilla based web app. It's going well but the session code doesn't work as I expect it to, [here is the full code](https://github.com/0xor1/gorillaseed/blob/master/src/server/src/api/v1/counter/counter.go#L43), and here is just the relevant snippet:

```
func getMyCounter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    session, _ := sessionStore.Get(r, counterSession)
    if session.IsNew {
        session.Values[myCounter] = 0
    }
    val := session.Values[myCounter].(int)
    log.Printf("getMyCounter %d", val)
    m := make(map[string]int)
    m["counter"] = val
    js, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(js)
}

func incrementMyCounter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    log.Println("incrementMyCounter")
    session, _ := sessionStore.Get(r, counterSession)
    if session.IsNew {
        session.Values[myCounter] = 0
    }
    val := session.Values[myCounter].(int)
    session.Values[myCounter] = val + 1
    getMyCounter(w, r)
}
```

my calls to getMyCounter and incrementMyCounter always return 0

Comment: you're not calling `session.Save(r, w)`

Comment: .... well this is embarrassing. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to JimB for pointing out the painfully obvious, I needed to add a call to `session.Save(r, w)` after creating/editing the session.

Comment: Just to add to this: if you have any control flow (e.g. you return early) you need to call `session.Save(r, w)` before you: a) leave the handler and/or b) write to the ResponseWriter.